# Как написать функцию для загрузки .mat файла и его обработки в классе?

Tags: python, matlab

у меня есть файл **`.mat`**. Хочу в классе преобразовать его и выполнять дальнейшие действия:

```
import scipy.io
import pandas as pd

class LunkaProcessing():
    def __init__(self, 
                 Lunka = None):
        self.Lunka = Lunka #сам подгружаемый файл
    
    def open_mat_file():
        mat = scipy.io.loadmat(Lunka) #конвертируем при помощи scipy
        mat = {k: v for k, v in mat.items() if k[0] != '_'} #препроцессинг
        self.data = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v[0]) for k, v in mat.items()}) #передаем его в пандас
        return self.data
    
    def initial_plot(self):
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
        plt.plot(self.data['t'], self.data['y']) #хотим построить график
        plt.xlabel('Время, с')
        plt.ylabel('Амплитуда')
        plt.legend()
```

При создании объекта класса:

```
lk = LunkaProcessing("Lunka_1.mat")
lk.open_mat_file
lk.initial_plot
```

и вызове функций получаю ошибки типа:

> <bound method LunkaProcessing.open_mat_file of <**main**.LunkaProcessing object at 0x000002906E2154F0>>
>
> <bound method LunkaProcessing.open_mat_file of <**main**.LunkaProcessing object at 0x000002906E2154F0>>

Что это вообще значит и как с этим бороться?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

P.S. сам файл **Lunka_1.mat** тут https://github.com/catauggie/mat-processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lk.open_mat_file
lk.initial_plot
```

Методы класса, как и функции, нужно вызывать с помощью круглых скобок:

```
lk.open_mat_file()
lk.initial_plot()
```

---

Ещё одна ошибка, которая вылезет, когда почините предыдущую:

```
    def open_mat_file():
        ...
        self.data = ...
```

Вы пользуетесь переменной `self`, которую не описали. Она должна быть в заголовке метода класса (это ссылка на экземпляр класса):

```
    def open_mat_file(self):
        ...
        self.data = ...
```

---

Третья ошибка - использование переменной класса `Lunka` как простой переменной:

```
mat = scipy.io.loadmat(Lunka)
```

Нужно её использовать так же, как в конструкторе:

```
mat = scipy.io.loadmat(self.Lunka)
```

В общем, все переменные, которые должны жить не только в рамках одного метода класса, но и сохраняться между вызовами методов, должны храниться в экземпляре класса `self` и обращение к ним должно быть через него `self.имя_переменной`.

---

По поводу последней ошибки. Что-то странное происходит, когда вы импортируете `scipy.io` и делаете вызов `scipy.io.loadmat` из класса:

```
import scipy.io
...
        mat = scipy.io.loadmat(Lunka)
```

Я так сходу не могу сказать, почему такой импорт глючит (причём только при вызове функции из класса), но исправление на более "скупой" вариант импорта (импорт только одной функции) у меня в `Google Colab` ситуацию исправило:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
...
        mat = loadmat(self.Lunka)
```

И вот такой вариант, рекомендуемый официальной документацией по сайпаю, тоже работает:

```
import scipy.io as sio
...
        mat = sio.loadmat(self.Lunka)
```

---

На всякий случай весь исправленный код:

```
from scipy.io import loadmat
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

class LunkaProcessing():
    def __init__(self, 
                 Lunka = None):
        self.Lunka = Lunka #сам подгружаемый файл
    
    def open_mat_file(self):
        mat = loadmat(self.Lunka) #конвертируем при помощи scipy
        mat = {k: v for k, v in mat.items() if k[0] != '_'} #препроцессинг
        self.data = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v[0]) for k, v in mat.items()}) #передаем его в пандас
        return self.data
    
    def initial_plot(self):
        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
        plt.plot(self.data['t'], self.data['y']) #хотим построить график
        plt.xlabel('Время, с')
        plt.ylabel('Амплитуда')
        plt.legend()

lk = LunkaProcessing("Lunka_1.mat")
lk.open_mat_file()
lk.initial_plot()
```

Comment: мне такая ошибка вылезает name 'Lunka' is not defined

Comment: как-то не могу сообразить, как передать подгружаемый файл в последующую функцию

Comment: ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 50, 52   это странно, без функции он нормально читался

Comment: здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525233/loading-mat-and-m-files-with-loadmat-in-python советуют пересохранить файл, но он и так читался в таком же куске кода вне функции

Comment: import scipy.io
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('Lunka_1.mat')   \\    import pandas as pd
mat = {k: v for k, v in mat.items() if k[0] != '_'}
data = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(v[0]) for k, v in mat.items()})

Comment: эти 5 строчек вроде читают файл довольно-таки быстро

Comment: даже файл на 211мб с 38М строчками читает быстрее самого матлаба

Comment: Так, ну я починил, почему импорт `scipy.io` глючит потом внутри класса сходу не могу сказать, нужно гуглить

Comment: а как это инициализировать?  lk = LunkaProcessing() или lk = LunkaProcessing("Lunka_1.csv") ?

Comment: Инициализировать как и раньше `lk = LunkaProcessing("Lunka_1.mat")`, я только сам вызов метода сделал без префикса полного имени, остальное ничего не меняется. На всякий случай я приложил весь исправленный код.

Comment: магия, но это работает, хотя ровно такой же самый код мой нет...  это странно, но ладно..

Comment: огромное спасибо

Comment: Ну вон даже в доке по сайпаю импорт рекомендуют такой: `import scipy.io as sio`, то есть дать псевдоним и через него работать. Как потом всё резолвится если такому импорту через точку не дать псевдоним для меня пока загадка, но корни глюка нужно искать в этом.

Comment: это правда... иногда на таких странных вещах многие начинающие сыпятся и ломаются...